# Display value of custom NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to be able to print my custom NSManagedObject in the console, to do that, in my object, I'm overriding the description method, like this:

```
@implementation Place

@dynamic libelle;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{libelle=%@, latitude=%@, longitude=%@}", 
            libelle, latitude, longitude];
}

@end
```

But I cannot access my @dynamic properties. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The property does not exist so we just need to use the accessor.

```
@implementation Place

@dynamic libelle;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{libelle=%@, latitude=%@, longitude=%@}", 
            self.libelle, self.latitude, self.longitude];
}

@end
```

Comment: "Although the description method does not cause a fault to fire, if you implement a custom description method that accesses the object’s persistent properties, this will cause a fault to fire. You are strongly discouraged from overriding description in this way." -Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using the property, not accessing the instance variables directly: `self.libelle`, `self.latitude` and `self.longitude`.